# How to get files in the subfolders too from directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, directory

Hi I have to get files from a specified path in the directory. This is the method I wrote but I didn't get the files from the subfolders.

```
Private void getfiles(){
Directoryinfo info = new Directoryinfo(configurationmanager.appsettings["Targetroot"].tostring ());
if (info.exists){
     Gvfiles.datasource = info.GetFiles();
     Gvfiles.databind();
   }
}
```

Comment: We need more details - what result did you get?

Comment: the code you have given should work fine check the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx)

Comment: In my code I get the files in the first folder, I want the files from the the folder which is placed in the first folder.too

Answer (score 17):

You will want to include the SearchOption.AllDirectories.

Example:

```
info.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143327(v=vs.80).aspx

And: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143448(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
DirectoryInfo info = new   DrectoryInfo(configurationmanager.appsettings["Targetroot"].tostring ());
//FileInfo[] _files = info.GetFiles("You could set a search pattern");
//FileInfo[] _files = info.GetFiles("*.aspx");
FileInfo[] _files = info.GetFiles();
Gvfiles.datasource = _files;
Gvfiles.databind();
```

or:

```
DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("/"));
DirectoryInfo[] _info = info.GetDirectories();
for (int i = 0; i < _info.Length; i++)
{
FileInfo[] files = _info[i].GetFiles("search pattern");
Gvfiles.datasource = files;
Gvfiles.databind();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But this code will not get the files from the folder inside the first folder, ineffect this is like my code

Comment: You can set path in directoryinfo(YourPath). Try Server.MapPath

Answer (score 0):

This returns an array of the (immediate) subdirectories:

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo ParentDirectory = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(ParentPath);
System.IO.DirectoryInfo[] DirectoryArr = ParentDirectory.GetDirectories();
```

I'm sure you can find a way to adapt it to your likings.

Answer (score 0):

```
private List<String> DirSearch(string sDir)
{
List<String> files = new List<String>();
try
{
    foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(sDir))
    {
        files.Add(f);
    }
    foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
    {
        files.AddRange(DirSearch(d));
    }
}
catch (System.Exception excpt)
{
    MessageBox.Show(excpt.Message);
}

    return files;
}
```